# Split a String and assign into variables

Tags: java

Lets say i have the following information about a airplane like its name,origin,maker,id,weight,fuel

Airplane,USA,boeing,1,45566,594829

How would I split up this information that is in a String and can I reassign the values like 1 , 45566,594829 into different variables in different classes?

**has to be in arraylist too*

Comment: `String[] words=your_string.split(",");`

Comment: So what would i type? like what code to assign those to different variable names?